# Set cookie in from joomla plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, fix-my-code, cookies

I want to display App download message(an image)to users browsing my site from Android device only. So i have developed a plugin to achieve this . Now i want to display this message only first time so, i need to set cookie. Here I'm checking if cookie is set first then don't display message else display message but condition is not working it is showing the message everytime.

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgsystemandroidmsg extends JPlugin {

    function onAfterRender() {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $htmlString = $app->getBody();
        if ($app->isAdmin()) {
            return;
        }
        $uri = JFactory::getURI();
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            if (stripos($ua, 'android') !== false) {
                $cookieName = 'mymsgseen';
                $cookieValue = $app->input->cookie->get($cookieName);
                if ($cookieValue != null && $cookieValue == 1) {
                    $htmlString = 'cookie is set : ' . $cookieValue;
                    $app->setBody($htmlString);
                } else {
                    $cookieValue = 1;
                    $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                    $app->input->cookie->set($cookieName, $cookieValue, $expire);
                    $htmlString = 'cookie is not set';
                    $app->setBody($htmlString);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

how can i achieve this? how to set and get cookies in joomla 3 ?

Comment: This source code seems Ok to me.

Comment: @Anibal, Then, What should be the issue here ? I couldn't understand also why it isn't working?

Comment: This is more for people googling their way here like me, but try setting the fourth parameter in `cookie->set()` to '/'. This makes the cookie available across the whole site, whereas the default value just stores it at the current path.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you could first try to fit this code in your template. If may give you more flexibility there.

`onAfterRender` does not seem right for me to fiddle the content and to set cookies / read cookies.

Are you sure that your plugin is actually being called? Anyway, check your browser console to see the status.

Comment: I have tried this on my localhost with joomla default template, it is working fine, do you have any suggestions why it is not working over dedicated server?

Comment: Is Joomla managing to send the session cookies?

Comment: Yes, It sets the session cookies. I verified it in firefox

Comment: This is working fine with same installation on localhost but not over dedicated hosting server. Please Suggestions